# Wireless not working after ubuntu 18.04 LTS installation

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, realtek

Like other posts my wireless connection to home network is not working after installing Ubuntu 18.04. I had Ubuntu 16.04 earlier on same HP laptop and never faced this issue.
Also I have Ubuntu 18.04 on Lenovo laptop and no issues on it, it works perfectly fine.

However I am able to connect using wireless to my iphone hotspot with no issues.
Whenever I tried to connect to home network first of all it takes long time and finally it says activation to network failed. Also wireless button on the keyboard doesn't work because i can not turn on/off wireless using the key.

I have tried multiple options mentioned in forum but none worked,

I would appreciate if anyone could help me here else i need to downgrade the version back to 16.04.

```
Laptop information -
description: Notebook
product: HP 15 Notebook PC (L0T31UA#ABA)
version: Type1 - ProductConfigId
serial: 5CD5323Y08
```

result of **lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net**

```
HP-15-Notebook-PC:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8179] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8188EE mini-PCIe card [103c:197d]
Kernel driver in use: rtl8188ee
Kernel modules: rtl8188ee
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 08)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [103c:21de]
Kernel driver in use: r8169
Kernel modules: r8169
```